# Hyperlink and fragment ID Vertical Offset Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

At the top of my page is an statically positioned menu strip which follows screen during scrolling.

When using fragment linking the scroll position needs to be offset by the height of the menu strip. How can this be achieved?

```
<a href="#fragment">Go to fragment</a>
<div id="fragment">...</div>

html { padding-top: 38px; } /* Offset page to allow for menu strip */
.menu-strip { position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; height: 38px; }
```

Is there a simple CSS change that can be made to achieve this?

Otherwise, is there a generic way to offset scrolling by 200px when a fragment is specified?

Comment: I don't understand the question, what is "fragment linking"?

Comment: it's hard to picture what you're describing. @vinceh I think he means hash linking.

Comment: @vinceh it's when you link to a specific part of a page. the web browser jumps to the element with the id specified in URI fragment. the uri fragment is the part after the hash.

Comment: @ilia the referenced element is positioned at top of screen (as it would normally be) but it appears beneath the menu strip. I basically need to offset vertical scrolling to compensate. if it is still to hard to understand I will put a demo page up tomorrow when I'm back at the office. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to do is make handle your own hash linking.  A good idea is to group all of your `a` that do hash linking.  For example

```
$(".ahashlink").click( function() {

    var location = $(this).attr("href");
    var offset = $(location).offset().top;
    $("body").scrollTop(offset+38);
    return false;
});
```

This will scroll to the correct place PLUS 38 more pixels (the height of your top bar).  This, however, will not change your URL in your browser to contain the right hash.  This is because once you have `window.location.hash = "#something"` then your window will automatically scroll to that hash.  So keep that in mind.

Comment: thank you for your response. this would also need to work between pages, so would need to be triggered on page load. I am surprised that web browsers don't automatically offset when `html { margin-top: 38px; }` is used, but I suppose this is a fairly rare requirement. thanks again

Answer (score 5):

This old article has an [HTML+CSS only solution](https://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/).

The basic idea is to use the [:before css selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp) to insert some hidden content before each linkable element to offset them:

```
<linked_elements>:before {
  display: block;
  content:" ";
  margin-top: -<offset>;
  height: <offset>;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e89kb28q/) of their [demo](https://css-tricks.com/examples/HashLinksWithPadding/pseudo.php).

This will also (I think) remove the need for `html { padding-top: 38px; }`